# Is it possible to connect a Chromecast to a 27" Cinema Display

Tags: hdmi, chromecast

I have a 27" Cinema Display that I also want to use as a TV replacement for some time.

The Cinema Display has a male Mini Display Portcable that easily connects it to a MacBook. There is no other input mechanism. The Chromecast also has a male HDMI connector to plug it into common SmartTvs.

Is there an adapter anywhere that connects those two cables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the signal from hdmi to mdp is not as easy as vice versa, you will need an adapter like this: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B003LGOWNQ?pc_redir=1399296085&robot_redir=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003LGOWNQ)